# How to get the schema name for sysobjects when querying a sql server database

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2012

I need to query a database for the name and schema name for all the stored procedures.

Here is what I've got so far but I do not know how to get the schema name.

What is the field name for the schema name when querying the sysobjects table?

```
  private DataTable GetProcedures()
    {
        var table = new DataTable();

        string sql = "";

        sql = "select name,'' as type ";
        sql += " From sysobjects ";
        sql += " where type = 'P' ";
        sql += " and name not like 'dt_%'  ";

        sql += " order by name asc";

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(cs))
        {
            conn.Open();

            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.CommandText = sql;

                using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                {

                    da.Fill(table);
                }
            }
        }
        return table;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this can help you :

```
SELECT name AS object_name 
  ,SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) AS schema_name
  ,type_desc
  ,create_date
  ,modify_date
FROM sys.objects
WHERE type = 'P'
ORDER BY name asc;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `sys.objects` table joined to the `sys.schemas` table like this:

```
SELECT schemas.name, objects.name
FROM sys.objects
JOIN sys.schemas ON schemas.schema_id = objects.schema_id
```

so to find all stored procedures (taking your query as a start), it looks like this:

```
SELECT schemas.name, objects.name
FROM sys.objects
JOIN sys.schemas ON schemas.schema_id = objects.schema_id
WHERE type = 'P'
AND objects.name NOT LIKE 'dt_%'
```

As additional information, you should no longer use `sysobjects` as it has been replaced with `sys.objects`, same goes for the other `sys*` tables.